# Dynamically set height of div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a webpage with 3 DIVs:

```
<header></header>
<article></article>
<footer></footer>
```

The height of the header is known, but change, as the contents change. The height of the footer is a known constant. Using JavaScript, I'm trying to set the height of the DIV such that the footer is pushed down to at least the bottom of the screen.If the page extends beyond the bottom of the screen the footer appears below the article DIV.

Background: I originally solved this using CSS Media queries in which I calculated the height as: calc(100vh - (header height + footer height));

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  article {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 250px) !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  article {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 237px) !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  article {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 217px) !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  article {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 201px) !important;
  }
}
```

The issue is that mobile devices to not recognize 100vh the same as is for desktop devices. Because of this, research told me to use javascript instead.

Using JavaScript, I'm trying to set the height of the DIV such that the footer is pushed down to at least the bottom of the screen.If the page extends beyond the bottom of the screen the footer appears below the article DIV.

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 992) {
      
      document.getElementById('article').style.setProperty('min-height', 'calc(window.innerHeight - 250)');

 } else if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth <= 991) {

      document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 237)";

 } else if (window.innerWidth >= 480 && window.innerWidth <= 767) {
   
      document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 217)";
   
 } else if (window.innerWidth <= 479) {
   
      document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 201)";
 }
```

I changed <article> to <article id="article">.

The height of the article DIV does not get set. I do not know why. When I try to alert the height of the DIV, I get UNDEFINED. Does anyone see why this is not working?

I've also realized that after I get the code to fire correctly on page load, I need to place it in a function and call it anytime the page resizes. How do I do that?

Comment: `<article>` doesn't have an id and your code has an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// alert = function() {};

window.onload = function() { resize(); }
window.onresize = function() { resize(); }

function resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 992){
        alert('Width 1');
        /*document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 250)";*/
        document.getElementById('article').style.setProperty('min-height', 'calc(window.innerHeight - 224)');
        alert(document.getElementById('article').height);
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth <= 991){
        alert('Width 2');
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 237)";     
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 480 && window.innerWidth <= 767){
        alert('Width 3');
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 217)";     
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth <= 479){
        alert('Width 4');
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight = "calc( window.innerHeight - 201)";     
    }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    article{
    min-height:calc(100vh - 250px) !important;  
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    article{
    min-height:calc(100vh - 237px) !important;  
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)  {
    article{
    min-height:calc(100vh - 217px) !important;  
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    article{
    min-height:calc(100vh - 201px) !important;  
    }
}

article{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<article id="article"></article>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: That JavaScript does not work. The article div does not resize to push the footer to the bottom of the window. In fact the gap at the bottom of the page is greater than what I tried before testing your code. Please try again.

Comment: That JavaScript does not work. what I mean is that everything looks perfect on the desktop, but in mobile the footer remains at the bottom of the article div but pushed down only as far as the contents of article force it to expand. Not quite what I expected. I want cross platform compatable Javascript that forces the footer at least to the bottom of the window.

Comment: I have updated. But actually it is a css problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
window.onload = function() { resize(); }
window.onresize = function() { resize(); }

function resize() {

    if (window.innerWidth >= 992){
        var H = window.innerHeight;
        H = H  - 250;
        H = H + "px";
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H;
    }

    else if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth <= 991){
        var H = window.innerHeight;
        H = H  - 237;
        H = H + "px";
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H;  
    }
    
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 480 && window.innerWidth <= 767){
       var H = window.innerHeight;
        H = H  - 217;
        H = H + "px";
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H; 
    }
    
   else if (window.innerWidth <= 479){
        var H = window.innerHeight;
        H = H  - 201;
        H = H + "px";
        document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H; 
    }
}
```